# Estate vs. Interest v. Right v. Title

Tags: legal-terms, property, real-estate

How do ***Estate, Interest, Right, Title*** differ from each other? Below, these different textbooks' glossaries fail to disambiguate them. Even worse, their definitions are circular! ***Estate*** is defined in terms of ***Interest***.  ***Interest*** and ***Title*** are defined with ***Right***, but nobody defined ***Right***!

| Term | Definition | Bibliography |
| --- | --- | --- |
| **Estate** | An interest in land that allows the interest holder rights of use and possession of that land for a particular duration. | [Bevan](https://global.oup.com/ukhe/product/land-law-9780192856760), page 631 |
|  | the length of time for which land has been granted to a tenant under the system of tenure. It means the duration of the grant. Note that this is a use of the word ‘estate’ that differs from the general use of the word; estate is used in this technical sense in land law. | [Clarke](https://global.oup.com/academic/product/land-law-directions-9780192856937), 484 |
|  | This is used in one of three ways. First it can mean the legal extent of person’s ownership rights in land. Secondly it can refer to the physical size of the land. Thirdly it can mean the entire property left by a person on death. The former category comprises either freehold or leasehold estates. Freehold estates are either a fee simple, a fee tail or a life estate. The context normally makes clear in what sense this word is used. | [Layard](https://global.oup.com/academic/product/thompsons-modern-land-law-9780198869061), 543 |
|  | An interest in land which entitles its owner to exercise proprietary rights over that land for a prescribed period. | [Nair](https://global.oup.com/academic/product/textbook-on-land-law-9780192858832?lang=en&cc=mn), 622. |
| **Interest** under a trust | Relationship between trustee (legal owner) and beneficiary (equitable owner) whereby the legal owner has to act for the benefit of the equitable owner, and the equitable owner has a right in the property which can be enforced against third parties. | [Lees](https://global.oup.com/ukhe/product/the-principles-of-land-law-9780198810995), 232 |
| **Interest** under a trust of land | A right relating to the freehold or leasehold estate which consists in the ability to hold the legal owner of the estate to account for the manner in which he manages his right, and which is itself a proprietary interest. | Lees, 23 |
| **Title** | Title describes the right to an estate, to ownership of land and serves as proof of that right | Bevan, 633 |
|  | The evidence of a person’s ownership of land, or the right itself. | Layard, 545 |
|  | A person’s right to property, or the evidence of that right. | Nair, 628 |

Comment: There are a finite number of words in English, so if you follow any chain of definitions for long enough, necessarily you will eventually either encounter an undefined term or a cycle.  At some point you have to rely on general knowledge.